# How to display value from the css file to console via console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

in this tutorial

```
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/custom-directive-in-angular/
```

the directive works as expected. however i would like to display the value of the color set on the console via

```
console.log
```

please have a look at my attempt in the code posted below, i used

```
    console.log(this.ttClass);//<---my attempt. it did not work
```

inside OnInit() but it did not work

please let me know how to display the value of the color from the css file on the console

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'ngDirective2';
}
```

**tt-class.directive.ts**:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
@Directive({
  selector: '[ttClass]'
})
export class TtClassDirective implements OnInit{

  @Input() 
  ttClass : string  ="";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.add(this.ttClass);
    console.log(this.ttClass);//<---my attempt. it did not work
  }
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

}
```

**app.coponent.html**:

```
<button [ttClass]="'blue'">Click Me</button>
```

**app.coponent.css**:

```
.blue {
background-color: lightblue;
```

}

**app.component.html**:

```
<h1 my-error>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<h2 *myCustomIf="condition">Hello {{name}}</h2>
<button (click)="condition = !condition">Click</button>
```

**image**:

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to see as an output `lightblue`? If this is the case, I don't think you can do it as you described. You should have your own preprocessor (I really can't see any reason why would you want to do so) or I am just missing something.

Comment: @pesoklp13 yes you got it right..I want to display the color on the browser’s console

Comment: I am just missing the purpose. Why would you do that? What's the reason? Do you want to do some specific logic based on that value? If that's the case you should definitely try to use a different commonly used approach instead. If you already know the name of the ccs class, you should be able to use the color directly. If you need to rely on the theme, well, the theme should be already known variable, so you should be able to compute your statement. But this is just my guess.

Comment: @pesoklp13 i am just new to angular and i want know the recommended way to achieve such an issue

Comment: @user2121, check out my answer.

Comment: based on @Bogdan B's answer it is not part of angular but HTML API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1):

Working solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcia4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftt-class.directive.ts

Also, styles should `ALWAYS` be modified via `Renderer2` in angular and not by directly accessing the `nativeElement`.

Comment: At least I know something new, but I still don't understand the need for such a thing :D

Comment: A complete explanation can be found here: https://betterprogramming.pub/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba . Also, TL;DR: "Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks. " and Renderer2 takes care of that,